# Finding a key in a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, key

i have created a hashmap with Color Objects as keys. My source code looks like this:

```
HashMap<Color,Integer> hm = new HashMap<Color,Integer>();
```

Now i would like to check if there is already a Color Object as a key in the HashMap. So i tried this:

```
if (hm.get(colorObject) != null){
```

Unfortunately it returns false, although the Color is the same. I print the color in the console and it is always `java.awt.Color[r=254,g=0,b=0]`. I also tried the method `containsKey` from `HashMap`.

So what is wrong? How can i check if there is an Object in the hashmap?

Comment: It should work if the `Color` object properly implements `equals` and `hashCode` (which i assume it does, since it's aparently `java.awt.Color`).

Comment: Its possible that you added null for this color in the map by mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `if(hm.containsKey(colorObject))`

Comment: OP has already tried that.

Comment: I tried containsKey again and it worked. Thanks. But i don't know why.

Comment: It's magic, it works..^^ Sorry, I missed that @NilsH

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
final Map<Color, Integer> colors = new HashMap<>();
colors.put(new Color(3030), 1);
System.out.println(colors.get(new Color(3030)));
```

and the output was 1, as expected. Therefore your problem is not as general as you have scoped it in your question.